# Ignore woocommerce pages from query

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

My standard query for pages is below.

```
$type = 'page';
$args = array (
 'post_type' => $type,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'paged' => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 50,
 'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
);
```

When I'm listing all pages in one page, how can I ignore woocommerce created pages like My Account, Cart, Shop...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly get woocommerce page ID's

```
if(class_exists('WooCommerce')){
  $woopages = array(get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_pay_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_edit_address_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_view_order_page_id' ),get_option( 'woocommerce_terms_page_id' ));
}
```

After that use query like this

```
$args = array (
 'post_type' => $type,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'paged' => $paged,
 'posts_per_page' => 50,
 'post__not_in' => $woopages,
 'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use wordpress [`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) to display **all the pages**. `wp_list_pages` has `exclude` parameter.

So with the help of that **parameter**, you can **exclude all the pages of woocommerce**.

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); //To get Cart URL
    $cart_id = url_to_postid( $cart_url ); //Convert that cart URL in to an ID

    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url(); //To get Checkout URL
    $checkout_id = url_to_postid( $checkout_url ); //Convert that Checkout URL in to an ID

    $shop_page_id = woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ); //Get an ID of shop page

    $myaccount_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ); //Get an ID of My account page

    wp_list_pages('exclude='.$shop_page_id.','.$myaccount_page_id.','.$cart_id.','.$checkout_id.''); //To list all the pages
?>
```

So with the help of above code, you can print all the pages and at the same time you can ignore woocommerce pages.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not listing just page names. I'm listing page contents in one page theme. Here is the my below code    $main_query = new WP_Query($args); 
    if( have_posts() ) :  
        while ($main_query->have_posts()) : $main_query->the_post();
        global $post;
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

Comment: Have try by including `post__not_in` in your `$args` ?

Comment: You can see [`post__not_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) and its usage.Make one array of the IDs from my code and exclude that array.

Comment: But woocommerce pages id changes every theme install how can I get id's of that pages?

Comment: Ok I found it. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: What solution did you go with ? If my answer helped you then you accept that answer so when someone come across same situation, that answer can be helpful for them. I guess My above code for getting woocommerce page will work for every theme.